# Change width of images in owl-carousel

Tags: javascript, html, css, owl-carousel

I am trying to change the width of the images in my owl-carousel.

```
            <!-- Slider -->
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="owl-carousel owl-carousel-fullwidth">
                        <div class="item"><img src="images/frontview.jpg" alt="image"></div>
                        <div class="item"><img src="images/entry.jpg" alt="image"></div>
                        <div class="item"><img src="images/register.jpg" alt="image"></div>
                        <div class="item"><img src="images/bulk2.jpg" alt="image"></div>
                        <div class="item"><img src="images/herbs3.jpg" alt="image"></div>
                        <div class="item"><img src="images/overhead.jpg" alt="image"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Slider -->
```

If I right-click on the image to inspect the element, it this inline style:

`<div class="owl-item" style="width: 960px; margin-right: 0px;">`

The only information I can find about width in the docs is about the autoWidth, which doesn't help me.

Any ideas? Thank you!

```
var owlCarouselFeatureSlide = function() {
    $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
        animateOut: 'fadeOut',
        autoplay: true,
        autoplayTimeout: 5000,
        autoHeight: true,
        items: 1,
        margin: 0,
        responsiveClass: true,
        nav: true,
        dots: true,
        // smartSpeed: 500,
        navText : ["<i class='icon icon-chevron-left'></i>","<i class='icon icon-chevron-right'></i>"]
    });
};
```

Comment: Are you only trying to change their width initially, or are you trying to set some specific widths based on the screen size (responsive)?

Comment: Just a simple question out of curiosity: Why are you not using the default [carousel component](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/carousel/) of Bootstrap (that you allready use) ?

Comment: @RyanWilson I want to set specific widths that are based on the screen size.

Comment: @johannchopin the owl carousel was already a part of the template that I am using - would changing to the bootstrap version benefit me? Apologies, I am pretty new to this.

Answer (score 0):

Owl Carousel dynamically sets the widths of div.item when the browser window resizes, but not elements within each div.item. So, you can provide CSS to do that. Since you're already using Bootstrap, have a look at these CSS classes that it provides https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/images/

Comment: Looks like Owl Carousel can also apply custom classes at various states of the carousel https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-classes.html